# How to upgrade from Anaconda 5.2 (that uses python 3.6.6) to Anaconda 5.3 (that uses python 3.7)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

## Background

I had Anaconda 5.2 with python version **3.6.5** On windows 10.
As the time of the writing, the latest Anaconda version is 5.3, which uses python **3.7.0**. The latest python release is **3.7.1**.

I used the following commands in cmd 2 times to update to the latest Anaconda:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

The end result of above is that, the Anaconda is now version 5.3, but python is updated to the latest 3.6, but not to 3.7

```
list anaconda
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                  Build  Channel
anaconda                  5.3.0                    py36_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.7.0                    py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py36_0

python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

## Question

how to update to the latest Anaconda with the latest python version it supports? 
(Besides Uninstall&Reinstall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update anaconda to be the same as the latest official fresh installation (anaconda 5.3):

```
conda install anaconda=5.3
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
conda install python==3.7.0
```

then just create new environment with python version you want, like

```
conda create --name python3_7 python=3.7.0 --channel conda-forge
```

**EDIT**: just tested on my mac terminal and

```
conda update python
```

updated my python version `3.6.5` to `3.7.0`

Comment: `conda update python` hit the spot! The conda's official documentation didn't mention it could do cross python version update.

Comment: Probably better to do `conda install python=3.7` so that you can get patch version number upgrades automatically (e.g., that would install 3.7.1 when it is available)

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is already the latest version but if you want to create python 3.7 environments you need to update python. Afterwards fire up Anaconda-Navigator and create a new environment and you will see "3.7" as one of your choices in the drop down menu.